# Trigger to keep account unlock history

Tags: oracle

How can create trigger that will insert username and date to a table,when oracle user account unlocked to keep account lock history

Answer (score 2):

You can write a database trigger like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER account_trigger
   BEFORE ALTER ON DATABASE
   WHEN ora_dict_obj_name = 'USER' 
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO LOG_TABLE (...) VALUES (...);
END;
```

Check [this document](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS794) to get more information

Maybe you can also use `AUDIT ALTER USER;` to get this information. See [AUDIT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_4007.htm)